Harry Potter fanfiction involving the wrong twin who lived
I've read this fiction in the last year, but cannot find it! I've posted everywhere with as much detail as I remember, but no luck. See if y'all can help!
Details:

Wrong twin who lived.
They have a younger sister.
Lily and James live.
Lily and James bond with the other siblings and Harry is slowly pushed/forgotten in the family. (Twin is BWL and baby sister is the token girl.)
Sirius tries his best to prioritize Harry.
Lily goes to hug Harry goodbye on Platform 9¾ and realizes she can't remember the last time she gave him affection.
MAYBE this happened, can't totally remember: Sirius was married to Andromeda and Harry was temporarily expelled after Dumbledore thought he was the heir of Slytherin. Harry had applied to Beauxbatons and Durmstrang before he was readmitted.


This one is vaguely familiar... especially the younger sister. Although I may be getting my wires crossed, because the other detail that comes to mind was that the relationship with the sister was a bit... charged.

Hmm... a whole list of possibilities at https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Wrong-BoyWhoLived/18135/

Also https://www.fanfiction.net/community/The-Potter-Twins/36759/
